# OpenSource: Encryption of JDBC Password in configuration properties file

Tags: rundeck

As I noticed a plugin available for the enterprise version (https://download.rundeck.com/plugins/encrypted-datasource-plugin.html); is there an option for users of Rundeck open source to perform the same kind of encyption of datasource password in the configuration file?

As I noticed many people mentioning writing their own java programs and leveraging the Jasypt utilities; I tried this.  I do have two jar files (one for encrypt and one for decrypt).  I created a directory (since I'm using rpm based Rundeck 3.3 installation) called: /var/lib/rundeck/lib .  I added this directory to the JVM classpath in /etc/sysconfig/rundeckd via: `export RDECK_JVM_SETTINGS="-Djava.class.path=/var/lib/rundeck/lib/*"`.  I converted my /etc/rundeck/rundeck-config.properties file to groovy format and updated the /etc/sysconfig/rundeck with: `export RDECK_CONFIG_FILE="/etc/rundeck/rundeck-config.groovy"`.  However when I change the /etc/rundeck/rundeck-config.groovy entry for datasource.password to:
`datasource.password=MyDecrypt("MyTest123Password")`; I get an error in the Rundeck logs after restarting:

> [2020-09-08T18:01:03,168] WARN  context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'application': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.util.ConfigSlurper$_parse_closure5.MyDecrypt() is applicable for argument types: (String) values: [MyTest123Password]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

That's encryption is only for Rundeck Enterprise, the best approach on Rundeck Community is to secure the `rundeck-config.properties` file through file UNIX permissions.